# Solr fl field name truncated?

Tags: solr

Solr seems to truncate the "fl" field name.  Is there a way to put it in quotes so it doesn't get truncated?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure Solr handles field names with dashes correctly, the documentation says that "It is strongly recommended that names consist of alphanumeric or underscore characters only and not start with a digit. This is not currently strictly enforced." https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html#field-type-definitions-and-properties

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you just need to add backslashes (`\`) before the special characters.

There is the full list of the chars to escape: `+`, `-`, `&&`, `||`, `!`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `^`, `"`, `~`, `*`, `?`, `:`, `/`.

Also, keep in mind special words: `AND` and `OR`. But if they're not CAPS, you shouldn't worry.

Please try it, if it doesn't help, share more details about your Tokenizers.